# Beginner Java code - else if condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I have no code experience and have just started learning Java.
I am not able to execute the below code and get below error when I try a sample else if loop. I am trying to check the percentage which tells us based on "per", the result is First class, second class etc

Error:

```
MyResult.java:19: error: 'else' without 'if'
```

```java
class MyResult {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double per = 65.56;
        if (per >= 75) {
            System.out.println("Result is FCD");
        }
        elseif(per >= 60); {
            System.out.println("Result is FC");
        }
        elseif(per >= 45); {
            System.out.println("Result is SC");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Result fail");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That else occurs well after the if block is closed.

Comment: put a space `else if` and remove `;`

Comment: Remove the `;`  after your `elseif`. Also, it's `else if` in two words, not `elseif`.

Comment: i would suggest using an IDE like NetBeans or eclipse (both free) if you aren't already

Comment: Kind of an interesting compiler nuance.  The elseifs are all wrong, but because of the semicolons they parse as valid method calls followed by unguarded code blocks.  Only after parsing would the compiler try to resolve the method `elseif` and fail.  So the error you get is for the mismatched "else" instead of the wrong elseifs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `elseif` keyword in java. You have to use two words seperated by space like `else if`.

Also, you need to remove semi-colon `;` after your `else if`.

So this `elseif(per >= 45); {` will become `else if(per >= 45) {`

Change other examples yourself and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon at

`elseif(per >= 45); {`

which marks the end of the corresponding `elseif` block. Just get rid of the semicolon and you are good to go.

Also, `elseif` should be `else if`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyResult {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double per = 65.56;
        if (per >= 75) {
            System.out.println("Result is FCD");
        }
        else if(per >= 60) {
            System.out.println("Result is FC");
        }
        else if(per >= 45) {
            System.out.println("Result is SC");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Result fail");
        }
    }
}
```